# Not able to run a command through ssh

Tags: ssh, unix, shell, freebsd

I am running a command on a FreeBSD machine (xxx.yyy.zzz.net) and getting the output

command

```
sudo camcontrol devlist | grep -o 'ada[0-9]' | while read -r a ; do sudo camcontrol identify $a | grep rotating ; done
```

output

```
media RPM             non-rotating
media RPM             non-rotating
media RPM             non-rotating
```

I am trying to run the same command using ssh from another machine

command

```
ssh xxx.yyy.zzz.net sudo camcontrol devlist | grep -o 'ada[0-9]' | while read -r a ; do sudo camcontrol identify $a | grep rotating ; done
```

error

```
sudo: camcontrol: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command, every `|` is interpreted by your local shell. The last argument `ssh` sees is `devlist`. `ssh` is invoked locally (this is no surprise), but so is everything after the first `|`.

The error you got came from `sudo` in this snippet: `do sudo camcontrol identify $a`. It run locally and apparently `camcontrol` is not available on the local machine.

You need proper escaping or quoting. In this case you may want to embrace the entire remote command in single-quotes:

```
ssh xxx.yyy.zzz.net 'sudo camcontrol devlist | grep -o "ada[0-9]" | while read -r a ; do sudo camcontrol identify $a | grep rotating ; done'
```

Note I changed single-quotes you already had. The (added) single quotes not only group the whole string so `ssh` gets it; they also prevent the local expansion of `$a`.

If `sudo` is going to ask for your password, it will need a pseudo-terminal. You can force pseudo-terminal allocation with `-t` option to `ssh` (so it looks like `ssh -t xxx.yyy.zzz.net …`). Note `ssh -t` allocates pseudo-terminal on the remote side. Remote `sudo` prompts to its stderr but then stdout and stderr are "printed" by this pseudo-terminal (like they are normally printed to the console) and at this point you can no longer tell them apart; the merged stream is captured and transferred to the local side where it goes to stdout. Without `-t` the remote stdout and stderr are transferred separately, go to stdout and stderr on the local side and these are eventually merged (or not, if redirected) into what you see. This means with `-t` you cannot (on the local side) distinguish remote stderr from remote stdout. If you need to locally process (redirect) the output further and you use `-t` then any prompt from `sudo` will interfere.

Also you probably want to double-quote `$a` (even in your first command that doesn't use `ssh`). See [*Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618)